# OBIEE - Schedule Export to FTP site

Tags: obiee

I am trying to export a file from OBIEE to an FTP server site on a regular basis. I found this link and I need exact same functionality

https://wapcobiee.wordpress.com/2015/08/27/obiee-send-content-to-ftp-server-network-folder/

I think this only works for environments where the BI server is installed on a Windows machine and our server is on Linux.Has anyone done this for a Linux server?

Answer (score 0):

Why? That is precisely what BIP bursting was invented for.

Comment: Thank you. I will try BI publisher (I think there is an option to use OBI reports as source)

Comment: I tried creating a BI Publisher report using OBI report as a source, added FTP destination under Manage BI Publisher and scheduled to run one time. Now I am getting this error   - Start Error; JMSAdminWrapper failed to start JMSWrapper, javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: <servcer name>:9704: Destination unreachable; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; No available router to destination].

Comment: Greetings! Were you able to fix this problem?